# Set the return value for a Python class instance when it is called by name

Tags: python, class

I have a Python class with the attribute `_mylist`. I want instances of `MyClass` to return `_mylist` when I call them by name. Here is the basic idea of what I want to define followed by example input and output.

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self._mylist = [a, b]

    def _returnlist(self):
        # method conferring MyClass with the property that calls to class
        # instances returns self._mylist 
        pass


>>> mc = MyClass(a, b)
>>> mc  # the desired property: call to mc returns mc._mylist
[a, b]
>>> k = mc  # assignment from mc instance only assigns mc._mylist
>>> k
[a, b]
```

Is there a standard way to give a class this property?

Comment: No, you cannot do that. Also it makes no sense to do that; how would it know when you wanted to access the list and when the actual instance?

Comment: No. Why would want to do this? Just *use the list*

Comment: overriding the method `__str__` could be a way but it can only return a string, and you will only be able to assign the result with `k = str(mc)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga perhaps I am over-complicating this. It appears the functionality I described is not possible.  Essentially MyClass is a glorified list and most calls to MyClass instances are for getting `_mylist` so I was trying to make things a bit cleaner. There are many other attributes, methods and properties that I left out for clarity but they are called less often.

Comment: @isosceleswheel IMO, that would make things *a lot less cleaner*. Sometimes your object would act like the underlying list-object, other times not. Sounds like a huge mess. There doesn't seem to be a need for your `_returnlist` function, though, just use the attribute directly: `ms. _mylist`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done.  Unlike, say, C++, Python does not give you a way to overload the meaning of `k = mc` so that `k` is instead set to `mc._mylist`.  In Python, `k = mc` will always set `k` to `mc`.